# How to get around limits overriding drop = FALSE in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot that has points coming from different data frames plotted over a raster object. I am using fill, size and shape aesthetics.

I am making many plots that I am printing out to a pdf on different pages.

Each page should show all possible options on the legend even if that plot doesn't contain those values.

I read that limits overrides drop = FALSE and hence drop = FALSE wont work seen as I am using limits.

I wondered if there was a work around of if there was an alternative to limits =

I have tried drop = FALSE within my scale_shape_manual and scale_size_manual.

I have also tried incorporating limits into the scale_shape_manual and scale_size commands. When I use limits like this the legend does stay the same however I lose data points that now apparently contain 'missing values'

I have tried to use guides() and ordered the items in the legend.

I have trawled stack over flow for an answer but haven't been able to implement anything successfully.

Please help.

Below is my code I believe the scale_fill_viridis_c(limits = cuberange) is overriding my drop and I haven't found an alternative.

My cuberange is just the min and max of the cube for that data subset.

I understand I have not detailed all the df used however I was hopeful someone had encountered and solved the same problem so I hoped this was not needed.

Thank you very much

plot script shown with limits however this does not work and neither does incorporating drop.

r_plot <- ggplot() +

```
  geom_raster(data=cube_df_filtered, aes(x, y, fill = z)) + 
  geom_point(data = pr %>% filter(year_start == years[i]), 
                      aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, fill = prevalence, size = point_cat, shape = quarter)) +
  geom_point(data = hf, aes(x = Long, y = Lat), colour="red") +
  geom_polygon (data = shps, aes(long, lat, group = group), colour = 'grey', inherit.aes = FALSE, fill = NA) + 
  coord_equal(xlim =bbox[1:2], ylim = bbox[3:4], expand = FALSE) + 
  scale_size_manual(values = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),name = "Examined",#drop = FALSE,
                    labels = c("<250", "250-500", "500-1000", "1000-2000", "2000-3000", ">3000"),
                    limits = c("<250", "250-500", "500-1000", "1000-2000", "2000-3000", ">3000")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = 21:24,name = "Year quarter",#drop = FALSE,
                     labels = c("0", "1", "2", "3"),
                     limits = c("0", "1", "2", "3"),
                     breaks = c("0", "1", "2", "3")) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(limits = cuberange) +
  scale_color_viridis_c(limits = cuberange) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = 'Longitidue', y = 'Latitude', fill = 'Prevalence', size = 'Sample Size', shape = 'Year quarter') +
  ggtitle(paste0('Cube: ', years[i]))
```

I am expecting to see a legend with 3 variables:
1) quarter using scale_shape_manual
2) Prevalence using the viridis scales
3) Examined using the scale_size_manual

But for some graphs I only see 2) Prevalence. When I incorporate limits into scale_size_manual I retain all variables but geom_point then contains 'missing values'.

Any advice would be great.
Thank you :)

Comment: Can you water down your question and provide a reproducible example?

Comment: I may be mistaken but I think if you use factors for your categories, the legend will contain all the levels. Just make sure to set the levels explicitly when casting to factor. In other words, you should do some pre-processing instead of relying on manual scales to print the "right" values.